# How do we get to the MSE in the loss function for a variational autoencoder?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, autoencoders, variational-bayes

Context: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf

So if I start with this equation:
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\phi} ; \mathbf{x}^{(i)}\right) \simeq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{J}\left(1+\log \left(\left(\sigma_{j}^{(i)}\right)^{2}\right)-\left(\mu_{j}^{(i)}\right)^{2}-\left(\sigma_{j}^{(i)}\right)^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^{L} \log p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\left(\mathbf{x}^{(i)} \mid \mathbf{z}^{(i, l)}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{z}^{(i, l)}=\boldsymbol{\mu}^{(i)}+\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(i)} \odot \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(l)} \quad$ and $\quad \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(l)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{I})$

So I'm looking at this part of the  equation in particular:
$$\frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^{L} \log p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\left(\mathbf{x}^{(i)} \mid \mathbf{z}^{(i, l)}\right)
$$

And I'm looking at it  where the decoder is a   multivariate Gaussian with a diagonal covariance structure:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{z}) &=\log \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x} ; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\sigma}^{2} \mathbf{I}\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

In this stackexchange discussion,
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27341/in-variational-autoencoders-why-do-people-use-mse-for-the-loss,  a few answers and comments talk about how manipulating this   particular log(p(x|z)) bgets something that resembles the MSE.

> So, if you are trying to predict e.g. floating-point numbers (in the case of images, these can be the RGB values in the range $[0,1])$, then you can assume $p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{z})$ is a Gaussian, then you can equivalently minimise the MSE between the prediction of the decoder and the real image in order to maximise the likelihood. You can easily show this: just replace $p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{z})$ with the Gaussian $\mathrm{pdf}_{1}$ then maximise that wrt the parameters, and you should end up with something that resembles the MSE.

And similarily in this discussion, [Loss function autoencoder vs variational-autoencoder or MSE-loss vs binary-cross-entropy-loss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350211/loss-function-autoencoder-vs-variational-autoencoder-or-mse-loss-vs-binary-cross), it is mentioned that

> If you assume it follows a normal distribution you will end up with a MSE minimization since $p(x \mid z)$ can be reformulated as $p(x \mid \hat{x}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{x}, \sigma)$

My question is, how do we show that this is true?

This is my attempt:

$$C= \mathbf{\sigma^2 I}$$
is the covariance matrix, and $$\sigma_i^2$$ is the ith diagonal values of this marix;

So then $$N(\textbf{x};\mathbf{\mu},\textbf{C})
=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{L/2} \sqrt{det(\textbf{C})}}exp(\frac{-1}{2} (\textbf{x}- \mathbf{\mu})^T C^{-1}(\textbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu}))$$

$$det(\textbf{C}) =\prod{\sigma_i^2}$$

$$ log(N(\textbf{x};\mathbf{\mu},\textbf{C}))=\frac{-L}{2} log(2\pi) + \frac{-1}{2} log(\prod{\sigma_i^2} ) + \sum{ \frac{(x_i-\mu_i)^2}{-2 \sigma_i^2}}$$

$$= \frac{-L}{2} log(2\pi) + \frac{-1}{2} \sum{\sigma_i^2}  + \sum{ \frac{(x_i-\mu_i)^2}{-2 \sigma_i^2}}
 $$

And from this point, I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from
$$
\frac{-L}{2} log(2\pi) + \frac{-1}{2} \sum{\sigma_i^2}  + \sum{ \frac{(x_i-\mu_i)^2}{-2 \sigma_i^2}}
$$

$L$, the dimension, is a fixed quantity. $\sigma$ is also a fixed quantity, with $\sigma_i = \sigma_j$ for all $i,j$ (you can choose to treat it as a variable, but this is rarely done, and doesn't lead to MSE). So we can drop the first two terms, since they are constant, and we're left with

$$
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_i{ (x_i-\mu_i)^2}
$$

Maximizing this quantity is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_i (x_i-\mu_i)^2$, which is MSE.

Comment: So I know   $$\sum{ (x_i-\mu_i)^2}$$ looks similar to MSE,but there is one thing I am not understanding.


Because typically if $$y_i$$ is the true label, and  $$\hat{y_i}$$ is the estimated label,
$$\sum{ (y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}$$ is the MSE , what is the $$y_i $$ and the $$\hat{y_i}$$ in 
$$\sum{ (x_i-\mu_i)^2}$$

Comment: @a12345 be careful not to conflate the i in your original attempt, which indexes the dimensions of each data point, with an i which indexes the data points. in this case, $y_i^{(j)}$, the $i$th dimension of the $j$th datapoint, is $x_i^{(j)}$, and $\hat y_i^{(j)}$ is $\mu_i^{(j)}$

Comment: Ok, thats interesting,but confusing.
Because the paper has the following formula:
 $\mathbf{z}^{(i, l)}=\boldsymbol{\mu}^{(i)}+\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{(i)} \odot \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(l)} \quad$ and $\quad \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(l)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{I})$
(using notation from the paper)
Then it gets fed to the decoder, which then outputs something. I thought that would be the 
$\hat{y}_{i}^{(j)}$ (using your notation in the comment) instead of $\mu_{i}^{(j)}$  (using your notation in the comment)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with shimao. $y_i^{(j)}$ is $x_i^{(j)}$, $\hat{y}_i^{(j)}$ is $\mu_i^{(j)}$ for jth datapoint.

But the $\hat{y}_i^{(j)}$(or $\mu_i^{(j)}$) should not be considered model output (estimated label). The model obtains the output by sampling in the distribution $N(x|\hat{\mu}_i^{(j)}, \hat{\sigma}_i^{(j)})$.

In VAE training, we don't need sampling in the decoder,no estimated label,  we just maximize the reconstruction loss $p(x|z)$,this is a likelihood, as shimao said, this is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_i x_i^{j} - \mu_i^{j}$, similar in form to MSE.